# How to use module in lib from controller with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, controller, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I created a module in my lib directory:

```
# lib/a/b/c.rb
 module A
   module B
     class C
       def say
         p 'Hi!'
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

Now I want to call C class from this module file.

```
# app/controllers/c_controller.rb
@data = A::B::C.new.say
```

And add this to config file:

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

But it gave me an error:

```
NameError in CController#index
uninitialized constant CController::say
```

Was my source wrong?

Comment: Did you include the module in the controller?

Comment: Yes. Even I do that as `include A::B` and use `C.new.say` in the controller. The same result.

Comment: Have you restarted your server after changing application.rb?

Comment: Yes. I restarted my server. I also created a new rails application to test it, the result was the same: `uninitialized constant`. I think it depends on Rails version. Now I am using 4.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the reason. It is necessary to add `require` in the first line of the controller:

```
require 'a/b/c'
```

Comment: It shouldn't be needed - this is why youa dd lib to the autoload path.

Comment: But if I don't use it. It really not work. Even I create a new project to test it.